# Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, templates, http-status-code-404

I looked at my files more than 50 times and i'm getting frustrated.
This is the error i'm getting:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in project1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^music/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Here is my urls.py in project1 folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

Here is my urls.py in music folder

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This is the installed apps in my settings.py for whatever reason:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: That error is pretty clear: you don't have an entry matching the `/` in your urlpatterns.

Comment: What happens when trying to load `http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/`?

Comment: It works fine when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/, i'm able to see the header and the words that I coded in there... its just that http://127.0.0.1:8000 and http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin doesn't work!

And what do you mean the enter matching the / in my urlpatterns? Isn't it in there

Comment: It isn't in there. The only valid paths you have end in `/music/` and `/admin/` because the request first has to follow the paths in `urls.py` in project1 before moving to the music folder.

Comment: How do I fix it? What do I enter in? Are you saying that i'm missing a file in the project1 folder?

Comment: The answer from @jnns addresses this. The _first_ patterns checked are in project1 `urls.py`, so `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),` in _music_ `urls` is actually equivalent to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/`. The new issue you're facing; do you actually have a function in `views.py` called `index` that can return some kind of response to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/`?

Comment: I found `django` documentation pretty confusing to get going if I'm honest. This guy produces really good tutorials that get you running pretty quick (django was actually pretty weak compared to his other topics) and should get you to the point you understand the basic structure https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs and the official documentation will then make more sense

Comment: Yeah, I defined the function index like here:

'from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>This is the Music app homepage")'

Comment: rename your main file index.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a good look at what Django tells you, why it couldn't find a corresponding page for your request URL:

> Using the URLconf defined in project1.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> ^admin/ 
> ^music/
> ```
>
> The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

It basically has just two views, that can handle your request and they are only reachable via `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`. You're trying to access content at `/` which just isn't there.

A solution would be to add another view as a root page or index page at the URL `127.0.0.1:8000` or change the URL of one of the two existing urlpatterns to match the root.

The following example adds a new view `index` to the root of your app:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', index),  # this is important and matches "/"
        url(r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls')),
        url(r'^credit/', include(extra_patterns)),
    ]
```

Comment: I did that and now its giving me this error in the shell:
NameError: name 'index' is not defined

Comment: Well, you'd have to write the index view first. Have a look at the section ["Writing your first view" from the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view).

Comment: @Chris You used `views.index` in your OP, try that.

Answer (score 1):

Either try the below url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/
```

or remove `music` from the url pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('music.urls')),
]
```